# UTF-8 String decoding in Python

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, utf-8, configparser

In a project I need a PHP and a Python module (Python 3.5.2). As well as a configfile which both modules use. The Python configparser has problems reading special characters from the configfile, like german mutated vowel (ä,ö,ü, e.g.). From the PHP side I use the utf-8 encoding to bypass the problem:

```
    utf8_encode ("Köln") //result: KÃ¶ln
```

From the Python side I tried the decode function:

```
    "KÃ¶ln".decode("utf-8", "strict")
```

I expected the result "Köln" but just got the result "KÃ¶ln" again.
What do I have do to do to decode my String?

Comment: Your `LANG` environment variable is set to a utf-8 locale, is it?

Comment: Can you verify the type of encoding used? You could try out `chardet` and use `chardet.detect(u"Köln")`

Comment: You should _always_ mention the Python version (preferably with a tag) on Unicode questions, because Unicode handling in Python 2 is quite different to how it works in Python 3.

Comment: FWIW, the UTF-8 encoding of `u"Köln"` is `b'K\xc3\xb6ln'`. But if you decode those bytes as if they were Latin 1, you get `"KÃ¶ln"`. So if you do `u'KÃ¶ln'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` you get the Unicode `"Köln"` back.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thanks. It works. But I found that the Python ConfigParser also stumbles over "Ã¶", so I can't store the string with that encoding. I found another solution, see my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try these lines added on the top of your document:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
# Encoding schema https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263
```

This may help you, more documentation [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263)

Comment: I got my error on runtime, working with string. The line, you suggested, is already included in my source code.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this you should add `#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` in the first line of your .py file.

Comment: How will that help here? The coding directive comment only affects how the interpreter decodes the script file itself, it has no bearing on how the script handles external data.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, all text is in unicode. So I would recommend, on your PHP side, converting the string to unicode (outputting as u'K\xf6ln'). After you've done this, you can convert it back to (sort of) it's original form in Python, however, the mutated vowel will be destroyed.

```
import unicodedata

unicodetext = u'K\xf6ln'
output = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicodetext).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

This will output a lonesome Koln, without the rather pretty mutation. From my research, I can't find any way around this, but please, anybody who finds a more apt solution please comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpfull answers and comments. I finally ended up with the following solution:

On the PHP side I encode my string with the following command:

```
$str = "path/to/file/Köln.jpg";
json_encode ($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The result is the string "path/to/file/K\u00f6ln.jpg" which is then stored in my config file.
The Python module uses ConfigParser to read the file. The encoded string is then decoded with the following command:

```
str.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')
```

The result is again "path/to/file/Köln.jpg".

Comment: Ok. If you're saving the data like that on the PHP side you should read the data in binary mode on the Python side. Then you can decode the bytes data like this: `data = b"path/to/file/K\u00f6ln.jpg"; s = data.decode('unicode-escape')`. That will work correctly on both Python 2 and Python 3. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.